# What's the name for those who take hitchhikers?

Tags: word-request

Is there a name for those who take hitchhikers in their cars? (compared with buyer and seller).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the point of view of the hitchhiker, you could call the person "a ride" (this is an example of metonymy). It is rather casual.

> Yeah, my first ride had this big moustache and spent the whole time talking about his pets.

You would not say "I am a ride". You would say "I pick up hitchhikers".  In more formal contexts "people who pick up hitchhikers" is the simple and plain way to express this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any single word. I've always just heard them called "people who pick up a hitchhiker" or some such phrase.